# Changing the data in a child component without changing it in the parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, onclick, state

I am making changes to a set of data and the data is held in a parent components state I pass that data to a 2nd component but when I make changes to the data in the 2nd component it is changing the data in the first. Ive tried setting a variable to the value of the state in an effort to make a copy of it / also creating a new state in the 2nd component that is set from the initial data from the first. But For some reason I am still changing the initial data. Can anyone explain whats going on here?

Parent Component:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [editing, setEditing] = useState(null);

{!!editing && (
        <EditInsurance state={editing} data={data} setEditing={setEditing} />
)}
```

2nd Component:

```
const [update, setUpdate] = useState([]);
const [List, setList] = useState([]);

//sets the data onLoad
 useEffect(() => {
    setList(data);
  }, []);

//edits the data
const handleClick = (item) => {
    let list = List;
    
    list.forEach((el) => {
      if (el.payerName === item.payerName) {
        el.state.push(state.value);
        if (!el.isActive) {
          el.isActive = true;
        }
      }
    });

    //update is an array containing only edited objects.
    setUpdate([...update, item]);
  };
```

When `handleClick` is fired and I console the `data` value in the parent component it has been updated. And I dont want to change that data until the user clicks save. How can I have a copy of the data exclusive to the 2nd component that doesn't manipulate the data in the Parent?

Comment: Objects in JavaScript are passed by a reference. You should clone the list instead of pushing to it.

Comment: You have a function to update the list: setUpdate, so use it instead of directly modifying the value 'List'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is that the code is mutating the state objects.

```
const [update, setUpdate] = useState([]);
const [List, setList] = useState([]);

// sets the data onLoad
useEffect(() => {
  setList(data); // <-- (1) parent state passed as prop
}, []);

// edits the data
const handleClick = (item) => {
  let list = List; // <--(2) reference to state in parent

  list.forEach((el) => {
    if (el.payerName === item.payerName) {
      el.state.push(state.value); // <-- (3) mutation of parent state!
      if (!el.isActive) {
        el.isActive = true; // <-- (3) mutation of parent state!
      }
    }
  });

  // update is an array containing only edited objects.
  setUpdate([...update, item]);
};
```

## Solution

Use/apply the immutable update patten. Any state that is being updated should be shallow copied into to new array/object reference. The spread syntax is a shallow copy by reference, this is why creating ***new*** array/object references is necessary to keep from mutating the original.

I'll assume that this child component just wants/needs to maintain its own copy of the `data` prop.

```
const [list, setList] = useState(data); // <-- (1) parent state passed as prop

// edits the data
const handleClick = (item) => {
  setList(list => list.map(el => { // <-- (2) array.map shallow copy
    if (el.payerName === item.payerName) {
      return {
        ...el, // <-- (3) shallow copy array element
        state: [...el.state, state.value], // <-- (4) shallow copy array
        isActive: !el.isActive, // <-- new property
      };
    }
    return el; // <-- not updating, just return current element
  }));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to copy the list using a spread operator. On the child component, you can do something like:

```
function EditInsurance(props) {
  const [parentData, setParentData] = useState([...props.data]);
  ...
}
```

And then use the parentData on your child component, you don't even need the useEffect.

Comment: This works in the same way with my original issue. The `data` in the parent component is still being changed. Ive even tried spreading the data as I pass it into the child component.

Comment: Have you deleted the useEffect as suggested? And replaced the list variable for parentData variable inside the handleClick?

Also, you can replace the handleClick for the code suggested on Fody response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure but you can try something like -

```
const [List, setList] = useState([]);
const [newList, setNewList] = useState([]);
```

and along with -

```
 useEffect(() => {
    setList(data);
  }, []);
```

use -

```
 useEffect(() => {
    setNewList([...List])
  }, [List]);
```

This will make a cloned copy of the List props that you received, and now if you change this (push or setState), your parent component will not reflect the changes.

Now in your handleClick function, -

```
    const handleClick = (item) => {
        let MyList = [...newList]

        # this is brcause you are using map. So first push the data in MyList and then setState your newList, so that child component can re-render 
        
        MyList.forEach((el) => {
          if (el.payerName === item.payerName) {
            el.state.push(state.value);
            if (!el.isActive) {
              el.isActive = true;
            }
          }
        });

     # also include this
     setNewList(MyList) 

    setUpdate([...update, item]);

}
```

and use newList everywhere in your child component render method.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need deep cloning to preserve individual objects in parent

```js
const [update, setUpdate] = useState([]);
const [list, setList] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const cloned = data.map(item => {...item})   // clone list and items
  setList(cloned);
}, []);

//edits the data
const handleClick = (item) => {
  list.forEach((el) => {
    if (el.payerName === item.payerName) {
      el.state.push(state.value);
      if (!el.isActive) {
        el.isActive = true;
      }
    }
  });

 setUpdate([...update, item]);
}
```

Your `handleClick()` can probably be shortened to

```js
const handleClick = (item) => {
  const payer = list.find(el => el.payerName === item.payerName);
  payer.state.push(state.value);
  payer.isActive = true;

 setUpdate([...update, item]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just get rid of the reference to props.data like so

```
function EditInsurance(props) {
  const [parentData, setParentData] = useState([JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(props.data))]);
  ...
}

                         OR
```

use lodash's clonedeep/clone method

```
function EditInsurance(props) {
  const [parentData, setParentData] = useState([._cloneDeep(props.data))]);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so the question is **why changing data from child component changes data of  parent component?**,the reason is objects in js are reference,
when you do something like this,

```
//sets the data onLoad
useEffect(() => {
   setList(data);
}, []);
```

both list of child and data of parent refers to same object in memory,changing something in list will directly reflected to data.and again you are trying to change state of parent component from child directly which is not a good practice. now you can make is work by creating new copy of data in child component, like this

```
//sets the data onLoad
useEffect(() => {
   setList({...data});
}, []);
```

but with spread operator inner nodes of data again will be shared with child component so better way is to make deep copy using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse

```
//sets the data onLoad
useEffect(() => {
   setList(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)));
}, []);
```

this way both child and parent component will have their own copy of data and changes from child will not be reflected to parent component,hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the other answers, and seeing as you haven't figured out a solution yet, have you tried cloning `data` before passing it down as a prop?

**Parent Component:**

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [editing, setEditing] = useState(null);

{!!editing && (
        <EditInsurance state={editing} data={[...data]} setEditing={setEditing} />
)}
```